# Javascript / jQuery chain sequencing with bootstrap 3 form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so here's my situation...

I've built a responsive landing page using Bootstrap 3 that is hosted through our email / landing page marketing automation tool called Marketo. The purpose of the page is for lead capture so right now I have 2 forms on the page, the responsive and aesthetically pleasing bootstrap form, and a hidden form that all of the information actually gets submitted through.

The hidden form that actually submits the information is pre-built in Marketo. They designed the forms to be implemented via drag and drop in their WYSIWYG editor or embedded manually. The issue is they aren't built to be fully responsive and it's a pain in the ass and more trouble than it's worth to get the form to behave the way I want it to which has lead me to this approach.

The problem I'm having is my hidden form is not actually submitting the information after it has received the valid input from my bootstrap form.

The solution I need help with accomplishing is writing a chain of javascript code that tells the bootstrap form to validate the entered input. When all of the input is valid, pass all of the information to the hidden form, and submit. All with one click of the bootstrap button.

Here is my javascript/JQuery code that I wrote for the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var validator = $("#resBSForm").bootstrapValidator({
            fields : {
                FirstName : {
                    message : "First name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your first name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                LastName : {
                    message : "Last name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your last name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Title : {
                    message : "Job title is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your job title"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Email : {
                    message : "Email address is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide a valid email address"
                        },
                        emailAddress : {
                            message : "Email address was invalid"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Phone : {
                    message : "Phone number is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide a valid phone number"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Company : {
                    message : "Company name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your company name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                NumberOfEmployees : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your number of employees"
                        }
                    }
                },
                callDate : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your call date"
                        }
                    }
                },
                callTime : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select a call time"
                        }
                    }
                },
                timeZone : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your time zone"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function fillForm(){

      var form1 = $('#resBSForm'), 
          form2 = $('#mktoForm_1867');  

      $('#BSFormBTN').click(function(){
        $(':input[name]', form2).val(function(){
          return $(':input[name='+ this.name +']', form1).val();
        });
      });

    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(function fillForm () {
        $('#BSFormBTN').click(function() {
            $('#mktoForm_1536 button.mktoButton').click();
        });
      });  
    });
```

Comment: Tip: validate on server side also as you have no full control on client side.

Comment: The hidden form already validates on the server side. The bootstrap validation is just to make sure that the information getting passed to the hidden form is valid.

Comment: i'm curious, why have two forms?

Comment: the basics would probably end up that the bootstraps "submit" button is really just an empty div and then listen to a click, fill out the hidden form and then you can just do $("hiddenform").submit()

Comment: also a bit confused on the problem: "The problem is the hidden form doesn't seem to be outputting the submitted information into the active campaign like it should be". how is it not putting it into the active campaign "like it should be" what should it be doing?

Comment: @Daemedeor 

The hidden form that actually submits the information is pre-built in our marketing automation service called Marketo. They designed the forms to be implemented via drag and drop in their WYSIWYG editor or embedded manually. The issue is they aren't built to be fully responsive and it's a pain in the ass and more trouble than it's worth to get the form to behave the way I want it to which has lead me to this approach.

The problem re-explained:

My hidden form is not actually submitting the information after it has received the valid input from my bootstrap form.

Comment: @Daemedeor The solution I need help with accomplishing is writing a chain of javascript code that tells the bootstrap form to validate the entered input. When all of the input is valid, pass all of the information to the hidden form, and submit. All with one click of the bootstrap button.

Comment: thanks, so for the form validator are you using 1000hz's bootstrap validator or nghuuphuoc's bootstrap validator? i ask because i don't know when the validator runs :P i think i can code something up after (also for future it'd be nice if you could edit your post as well to reflect the goals so people don't have to scour the comments)

Comment: Right now I believe i'm using nghuuphuoc's but I'm going to switch to 1000hz's because it appears to be more up to date.

Your suggestion has been noted. This is my first post on here so I've edited it to reflect my goals more clearly. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your live validation is fine, the HTML is the standard HTML for a form and what is shown in the js code, this is just a quick implemenation based off on your current question. i'm sure it could be improved. Since you have indicated a change in validations, i would suggest that your validation comes before the reading of all the input fields in the with your given method (it should be documented somewhere) but it should be easy to implement.

```
var form1 = $('#resBSForm'), 
    form2 = $('#mktoForm_1867');

$(document).ready(function () {
        var validator = form1.bootstrapValidator({
            fields : {
                FirstName : {
                    message : "First name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your first name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                LastName : {
                    message : "Last name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your last name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Title : {
                    message : "Job title is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your job title"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Email : {
                    message : "Email address is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide a valid email address"
                        },
                        emailAddress : {
                            message : "Email address was invalid"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Phone : {
                    message : "Phone number is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide a valid phone number"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Company : {
                    message : "Company name is required",
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please provide your company name"
                        }
                    }
                },
                NumberOfEmployees : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your number of employees"
                        }
                    }
                },
                callDate : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your call date"
                        }
                    }
                },
                callTime : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select a call time"
                        }
                    }
                },
                timeZone : {
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Please select your time zone"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function (){
      var form1Submit = $('submitBtn', form1);

      form1Submit.click(function(){

        $('input', form2).toArray().forEach(function(e){ 
           //might want to actual validate what this returns on form submit 
           var form1Input = $("input[name='"+e.name+"']", form1).val();
           $(this).val(form1Input);
        });

        form2.submit();
      });

    });
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me.

I was able to figure out how to do it using jQuery alone without any validation plug-ins however I would prefer to be able to add validation rules and show / hide help text.

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adykstraAFR/uwfw3muk/5/#&togetherjs=94c6UqydCg)

Comment: @AnthonyDykstra so you want a full validation, the UX and the help text?  i didn't really test the script so it was more psudeocode in the close enough vacinity

Comment: I've abandoned trying to get this to work. My next endeavor is to try to use jQuery to remove all of the classes / styles of an embedded form and replace them with either the bootstrap class styles or my own. Is this a relatively simple task?

Comment: @AnthonyDykstra well you can adding the classes i guess can be simple ~